# Windbg: "gu" command inside of a breakpoint causes warning

Tags: windbg, breakpoint

I'm trying to leverage "gu" command in a conditional breakpoint or as a ["CommandString"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bp--bu--bm--set-breakpoint-) in a regular breakpoint. For example let's consider break on a malloc() function when we want to see in logs what pointer was allocated and what was the size of an allocation:

```
bp msvcrt!malloc "r $t1=@rcx; gu; .printf \"malloc: %p %08x\\n\",@rax,@$t1; gc"
```

> tldr: So, we've created a temporary register $t1, assigned it to the
>   size of allocation (the arch is x64,  thus @rcx = "size"), steeped out
>   of the function using "gu" command, and finally printed pointer at
>   @rax plus our temp register value. You can try it yourself with a "notepad.exe" ;)

It's kind of working, we can see the data:

```
Some commands were skipped because previous commands caused target execution inside an event handler.malloc: 000001d2e78d42c0 00000100
Some commands were skipped because previous commands caused target execution inside an event handler.malloc: 000001d2e78d4700 00000088
Some commands were skipped because previous commands caused target execution inside an event handler.malloc: 000001d2e78d47c0 00000088
Some commands were skipped because previous commands caused target execution inside an event handler.malloc: 000001d2e78d4880 00000038
Some commands were skipped because previous commands caused target execution inside an event handler.malloc: 000001d2e78d4f10 000000f0
Some commands were skipped because previous commands caused target execution inside an event handler.malloc: 000001d2e78d5030 00001124
Some commands were skipped because previous commands caused target execution inside an event handler.malloc: 000001d2e78d6190 00002430
Some commands were skipped because previous commands caused target execution inside an event handler.malloc: 000001d2e78d85f0 00000200
Some commands were skipped because previous commands caused target execution inside an event handler.malloc: 000001d2e78d8820 00000080
Some commands were skipped because previous commands caused target execution inside an event handler.malloc: 000001d2e78d88d0 00000080
```

With the only small exception which is noisy string
"Some commands were skipped because previous commands caused target execution inside an event handler.". It seems it's always in a logs when we're using "gu" as a "CommandString".

Any ideas how to get rid of it or what is the intended way of solving such a problem?

Regards!

Comment: UPD: Aforementioned example is working in windbg but not in windbg preview. It may be that "gu" is not intended to be used in this case :(

Comment: One way of solving this is to put two breakpoints: one at the start and second in the end of the function.

```
bp msvcrt!malloc "r $t1=@rcx; gc;"
r $t0=msvcrt!malloc+cc
bp @$t0 ".printf \"malloc: %p %08x\\n\",@rax,@$t1; gc"
```

This works but it certainly looses it's elegance

Answer (score 2):

take a look at [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-session-and-execution-model)

so you cannot use a command that alters the execution status inside a wait

I am not sure what your intent is

but windbg provides several PseudoRegisters to access state and act upon

one is **@$ra**  which is the Return Address on the stack this is wher your gu will actually endup

others are **@$retreg and @$retreg64**
these are actually the returns from a function (or in layman's term **eax and rax** after a call is executed

so basically some xyz is calling  malloc like malloc(size) 
you have set up a break on msvcrt!malloc 
@ra will contain the xyz + (size of call) that is the address of Return from the call 
and if you had issued gu 
you will land here and when you have landed here rax/eax as well as @$retreg/@$retreg64 will contain the Address of Allocated memory from the malloc call

you can also set a one shot breakpoint

you can combine all this to make a concise breakpoint  that will print both the size as well as returned pointer

```
0:002> bl
     1 e Disable Clear  00007ff8`c8199d30     0001 (0001)  0:**** msvcrt!malloc "bp /1 @$ra \"? @$t1;?@$retreg64;gc\";r $t1=@rcx;gc"
windbg> .hh
0:002> g
Evaluate expression: 40 = 00000000`00000028
Evaluate expression: 2051178946016 = 000001dd`93cadde0
Evaluate expression: 256 = 00000000`00000100
Evaluate expression: 2051178943712 = 000001dd`93cad4e0
Evaluate expression: 40 = 00000000`00000028
Evaluate expression: 2051178944016 = 000001dd`93cad610
Evaluate expression: 24 = 00000000`00000018
Evaluate expression: 2051178947056 = 000001dd`93cae1f0
Evaluate expression: 32 = 00000000`00000020
Evaluate expression: 2051178947328 = 000001dd`93cae300
Evaluate expression: 32 = 00000000`00000020
Evaluate expression: 2051178949536 = 000001dd`93caeba0
Evaluate expression: 72 = 00000000`00000048
Evaluate expression: 2051178946272 = 000001dd`93cadee0
Evaluate expression: 32 = 00000000`00000020
Evaluate expression: 2051178947056 = 000001dd`93cae1f0
Evaluate expression: 32 = 00000000`00000020
Evaluate expression: 2051178944016 = 000001dd`93cad610
Evaluate expression: 672 = 00000000`000002a0
Evaluate expression: 2051178949824 = 000001dd`93caecc0
Evaluate expression: 104 = 00000000`00000068
Evaluate expression: 2051178946272 = 000001dd`93cadee0
Evaluate expression: 32 = 00000000`00000020
Evaluate expression: 2051178946432 = 000001dd`93cadf80
```

notice the escaped command string in the bp

**bp msvcrt!malloc "bp /1 @$ra \"? @$t1;?@$retreg64;gc\";r $t1=@rcx;gc"**

if you need to use .printf you may need another level of quote escaping